# Django Sharing Large File Repository Between Development and Production

Tags: django, django-models, django-staticfiles, django-storage

I'm trying to develop a Django application that will eventually serve a large media file repository (10's to 100's of GB) that would ultimately be stored on B2 or S3 instead of locally on the server.

For application related static content, I think I understand that you will have a /static/ in your application tree, and a /static/ in your web server tree. When you run `python manage.py collectstatic` the files are compared, and the web server file tree is updated based on the application file tree.

Since these would ultimately be uploaded by a user, should I instead be thinking of the `MEDIA_ROOT`and `MEDIA_URL` settings? These would then be staging areas prior to preparation and upload to B2 or S3.

I've checked these out:

[Identical and simple way of serving static files in development and production - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829928/identical-and-simple-way-of-serving-static-files-in-development-and-production)

[Django: Deploying static files in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396009/django-deploying-static-files-in-production-environment)

[serving django media (user uploaded) files in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707680/serving-django-media-user-uploaded-files-in-production)

[Serve media files with a static service. Dotcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727085/serve-media-files-with-a-static-service-dotcloud)

and I feel like they are probably starting down the right path, but there is minimal discussion so I don't know the alternatives.

Are there other approaches I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this [Blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html).

You could basically run `python manage.py collectstatic` only on your development server to push the files to **S3**. Than you don't need to add the images to your versioning and Django server.

If you want you also want versioning of the images I recommend [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com).